# Custom text in navigation bar

Tags: ios, uilabel, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I want to set a text on the position of `leftBarButtonItem`/`rightBarButtonItem` in the `UINavigationBar`. You have to use `UIBarButtonItem`, but you can put different `UIView` objects into it. First I tried to use a label, but that doesn't work. The code is in C#, but you should get the idea:

```
UILabel textLabel = new UILabel();
textLabel.Text = "My custom text which should be displayed in navigation bar";
UIBarButtonItem customBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem (textLabel);
NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = customBarButtonItem;
```

The label is not shown. If I use a button it seems to work (except the styling has to be adapted).

```
UIBarButtonItem customBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem ("My custom text which should be displayed in navigation bar", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,null);
NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = customBarButtonItem;
```

Why isn't it possible to use a `UILabel`? What is the correct way of showing a text like a header in a `UIBarButtonItem`?

**Edit:**

My current findings are:

Either set the title of `UIBarButtonItem` or set the frame of `UILabel` (thanks to Anbu.Karthik for this).

Comment: You better show the real code and stick to naming conventions. This is rather guess work.

Comment: @HermannKlecker: I edited my question to have some more meaningful placeholders. The code is what I want to use later. Only the content would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
UILabel testLabel = new UILabel();
testLabel.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21);

testLabel.Text = "yuhu";
UIBarButtonItem test = new UIBarButtonItem (testLabel.text);
```

Comment: else check the label frame is necessary or not

Comment: The only constructor I see is the one I used in my question (you need some more parameters). FIrst, I tried to use auto layout which leads to a crash because he doesn't know the parent. Now I tried to set the frame and the label gets displayed! How would the same thing work with auto layout? Where do I have to add the constraints? The `View` of `UINavigationController`?

Comment: if you use the label in directly in your view then you can thing about auto layout , but UIBarbutton does not underwith in any chain hierarchy , so in here only need to move/assign the label text to bar button text , so label frame is fine for here

Comment: If I understood you correctly I can safely set the frame and forget auto layout for this case (because it Isn't in any view hierarchy)?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your answer, where you say that I have to set the frame. Then I can upvote it.

Comment: in here if you try to use auto layout , surely your app will crash the reason is not a UIButton , UIButton has chain hierarcy , but UIBarbutton contains not

Comment: I don't know if everything is Objective-C/Swift code of your solution. Perhaps you could check that so this is general solution not only for me.

Comment: sure my friend I follow and Update my answer in soon

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code `UIBarButtonItem test = new UIBarButtonItem (testLabel);`

```
UILabel testLabel = new UILabel();
testLabel.Text = "yuhu";
 testLabel.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
//change this line

UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:testLabel];
NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = test;
```

Comment: If I translate that into the C# world this is exactly the same line `UIBarButtonItem test = new UIBarButtonItem (testLabel);` if *btn* is *testLabel*. Or do you mean `UIButton`?

Comment: I only want to display a text. The first idea for this is to use `UILabel`, but that didn't worked for me.

Comment: but a label will not give any meaning to bar button as it will not have any action.are u planning to add to tap gesture to uilabel

Comment: It should only display a text. No action required here.

Comment: Yep, Anbu.Karthik told me to do that and it works. The successive question is how would that work with auto layout? Or which frame values should I set? Try and error?

Comment: give it according to navigation bar width and height like let make it like bar button `CGRectMake(16,20,50,44)`

Comment: Is this the position and size of the back button? It would be nice to have auto layout working or the system deciding the max. available width and so on. But I can't add a constraint to `UIBarButtonItem`. The app crashes if I would try to add the constraints to the view of the navigation controller.

Comment: i don't thin so constraint will work, U may have to go frame based

Answer (score 0):

Use  this

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```